# Reactjs POST request through fetch

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, rest, fetch

Hi i am trying reactjs POST request through fetch but getting two error's, I went through all docs but error is not solved.

Errors:

1. Failed to load http://localhost:8083/students: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
2. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Here is my Reactjs code:

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import axios from 'axios';
const style = {
 margin: 15,
marginLeft: 600
};
export default class  Register extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.onSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}


handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var self = this;
   var data = new FormData();
   const payload = {
   id: 111,
   studentName: 'param',
   age: 24,
   emailId: 2
};
data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));

fetch('http://localhost:8083/students',{
   method: 'POST',
   body: data,
   headers: {
    // 'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
 })
   .then(function(response) {
       return response.json()
     }).then(function(body) {
       console.log(body);
     });
 }

render() {
   return (
     <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
     <div style={style}>
     <TextField ref='id'
     hintText="Enter Student id"
     floatingLabelText="id"
     />
     <br/>
     <TextField ref='sname'
     hintText="Enter your Last Name"
     floatingLabelText="StudentName"
     />
     <br/>
     <TextField ref='age'
     hintText="Enter your Age"
     floatingLabelText="age"
     />
     <br/>

     <TextField ref='emailId'
     hintText="Enter your Email"
     floatingLabelText="emailId"
     />
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" />


     </div>
         </form>


   );
 }


}
```

Even though here my form values also hard-coded.

Comment: Code 403 means forbidden, check your API's authorización

Comment: I see your authorization header token is commented out. If that's not included you'll get a 403 since the fetch won't be authorized

Answer (score 0):

The error: `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403` means you don't have access to post data to the server. This security policy is called as CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Here you must have an API server. The server must allow requests from localhost:8083.

To allow such requests, you can add headers to apache configuration files:

I use following configuration in my apache config file:

```
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8083"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method,X-Requested-By, Access-Control-Request-Headers,withCredentials"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true'
```

Edit: To add open your apache configuration file and add the above lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ......
    ......
    ......
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:8080"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method,X-Requested-By, Access-Control-Request-Headers,withCredentials"
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true'
</VirtualHost>
```

The path for the configuration file is: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`, which might be different in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Could you please tell me how to add headers to the apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

1-  `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403`, means that you need to send the authorization token in header (it's commented out)

2- `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch` means the the server is not sending a respose with `JSON` format then  `response.json()` is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you use `FormData`, with `Content-Type` header `application/json` which is wrong.

```
var data = new FormData();
```

Another point to raise here is you can't set `JSON` inside `FormData` like this.

```
data.append("myjsonkey", JSON.stringify(payload));
```

Firstly what kind of payload do you need to send. Use `multipart` `FormData` only if you need to send files to the server. If you do so, make sure you **remove** the `Content-Type` header from your request.

Or else, if you want to send JSON data create a proper JSON payload and send it instead of `FormData`. That should work.